# wamp server maximum execution time error

Tags: php, wordpress, server, wamp

I am trying to put wamp server online, but always getting wamp server maximum execution time of 30 seconds error.

Using responsive theme, I changed `max_execution_time =300 SECS` in php.ini development and production files, but can't see any change. It still shows the same error in WordPress... any page I open.

Comment: did you restart apache? did you check for any OTHER php overrides elsewhere, like `php_value` in .htaccess or some other .conf file?

Comment: Yes I did that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try to change the php.ini file within wamp directory. instead of using theme options. Just go directly into wamp. That's the file that wamp will use.

Comment: WhIch directory phpforapache.ini?

Comment: Create a info.php file ... <?php  phpinfo();  ?> ........ Then find Loaded Configuration File. In that row shows the directory of your php.ini file